# Git color-interface will not work with Cygwin

Tags: windows, git, user-interface, colors, cygwin

I just switched over from MINGW32 to Cygwin, and am having some trouble with Git. For some reason, when using Git there is no longer a colorized output. So, I am having trouble reading anything.

I have tried adding the following to the *config* file in my repo:

```
[color]
  diff = auto
  status = auto
  branch = auto
  interactive = auto
  ui = true
  pager = true
```

Also, I have tried executing the following command...

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

However, none of this has helped. I just have a black background with white text as the output from anything I try to do.

How do I turn on the Git "colored" interface in *Cygwin*.

Comment: It works for me. And I have just `[color]  ui = auto` on .gitconfig

Comment: (dot)gitconfig @matzeri ???

Comment: yes. on my home directory